# Parsing .html as PHP: how to check which method would be right?

Tags: php, linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, lamp

The usual way of parsing `.html` files as PHP is to add either the first (PHP as an Apache module) or both (PHP as CGI) of the following lines to an `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Sometimes that needs to be `x-http-php5`, depending on the host:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

However, I am now on a new host and no permeation of those lines work. In all cases the raw file is being sent to the browser, and `wget` shows that `x-httpd-php` is being presented as the Content-Type!

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 07 Aug 2012 14:16:40 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Aug 2012 07:46:44 GMT
  ETag: "862239-14-4c6a83216c100"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Length: 20
  X-Powered-By: PleskLin
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
Length: 20 [application/x-httpd-php]
Remote file exists.
```

Note that `Length: 20` is exactly the length of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, and that is what it is serving. I have confirmed that PHP is running as a module with the terrific tip [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369879/343302). I have spoken with the maintainer of the server (an associate, so even if I switch hosts I would still like to help him resolve the issue) and he does not know what the issue or correct configuration is. The server is running Plesk on a Debian-based distro, if that matters at all.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate in ServerFault, but I'm pretty sure it would be a duplicate there.

Comment: I think that you're right, this would be better off on ServerFault. I don't have move permissions, though. A quick look around there only finds people asking how to configure their `.htaccess` files to parse `.html` files as PHP, but no questions as to how to configure the server to support it. So, this is not a dupe. (I wish that it were!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact an Apache configuration issue, this page had the solution:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/124

Reproduced here for posterity:

> .htaccess files can be enabled by placing the following in the
>   "/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz010_psa_httpd.conf" file:
>
> ```
> AccessFileName .htaccess
>
> <Directory "/var/www/vhosts">
> Options +All
> AllowOverride All
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> Then restart Apache:
>
> ```
> #service httpd stop
> #service httpd start
> ```